# How to open BottomSheetDialog inside fragment

Tags: android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I want to open BottomSheetDialog from fragment. Before it, I tried opening BottomSheetDialog at activity and it worked. I use the same code and replace the `getSupportFragmentManager` with `getChildFragmentManager`. I also tried replacing the getSupportFragmentManager  with `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager` . Is there a solution?

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements BottomSheetDialog.BottomSheetListener {

private TextView mTextView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beranda, container, false);
    Button buttonOpenBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.button_open_bottom_sheet);
    buttonOpenBottomSheet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new BottomSheetDialog();
            bottomSheet.show(getChildFragmentManager(),"BottomSheet");
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try BottomSheetDialogFragment

ModalBottomSheetDialogFragment.Builder()
        .add(R.menu.menu_options)
        .show(childFragmentManager, "my_bottom_sheet")

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alfredo, But I,am already using BottomSheetDialogFragment. In my code my Main activity implements BottomSheet class. In BottmSheet class, the BottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment. Do you know where's the problem?

Comment: I have the same situation , but my parent fragment does not implements implements BottomSheetDialog.BottomSheetListener, 

I call child fragment this way :

val fragment = BottomSheetDialogConfirmarReservaFragment.newInstance("parameterOne")
                fragment.show(childFragmentManager, "Confrim Fragment")